# Native theme interfering with custom theme link

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create custom theme for a link. seems to work fine in jsfiddle. But in my page, native themes take precedence. "SHOW MORE" at the bottom of the page should be purple in color. but its still in blue.

```
>     .ui-link-prp,
>     .ui-link-prp:visited,
>     .ui-link-prp:hover,
>     .ui-link-prp:active{
>       color: #9e0249;
>       font-size: 14px; 
>       font-weight: bold;
>       text-decoration: none;
>     }
>     
>     <ul>
>          <li><a href="#" class="ui-link-prp" data-theme="prp">show more</a></li>
>      </ul>
```

here is the [link](http://haripriyaa.zymichost.com/ot/profile.html)

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `!important` ...

```
   ...{
        color: #9e0249 !important;
        font-size: 14px !important; 
        font-weight: bold !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
     }
```